# DataGrid columns color, font

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I need to set a column's background color, font size, etc. in a `DataGrid`. I have read a lot but can't find a working solution. The column color and font should be set for each column as the table is loading from a database based on the table.

Is it possible to set these properties for individual cells in the `DataGrid`'s `LoadingRow` event.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in the RowDataBound event.